# mathspec and unicode-math characters not displayed

Tags: unicode-math, mathspec

I have using `mathspec` and `unicode-math` for the purpose of two different math symbols in my documents. I have used as per this [how do set table body math parts in different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225529/how-do-set-table-body-math-parts-in-different-font/225537#225537). But when using `$...$` the symbols are not displayed. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[no-math]{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times}
\setmathsfont{Times}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=table]{Helvetica}
\newfontfamily\tablefont{Helvetica}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\setmainfont[Color=black, Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Cn}}%
 \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\mathversion{table}\tablefont\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}}%
    \begin{document}
            \title{Geometry}
    \maketitle
From the Egyptian pyramids to modern architecture, points, lines and   angles
are everywhere. $a^\circ$ Geometry is a $\alpha + \beta$ very visual    element of mathematics where the
designs of buildings and the orbits of planets can be studied using basic
objects like points, lines and circles.

   \begin{table}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{L{2cm}|L{10cm}}
        \hline
       \thead{Variabili} & \thead{Descrizione} \\
        \hline
        \thead{$\alpha + \beta$} & \thead{$a+b$}\\
        \hline
    gdp\_us & GDP USA trimestrale nominale (dal Q1 1947 al Q4 2013), fonte: FRED2\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

Thales (624--546~BCE) is known to be the founder of Greek geometry. He was
an astronomer and $a^\circ$ philosopher, and $\alpha + \beta$ records  show he was the first person to
use mathematical geometry to calculate the height of an Egyptian   pyramid
using the Sun's rays and to accurately predict the timing of a solar
eclipse.
    \end{document}
```

Comment: As I said in the other question, you have to use fonts with math tables, like `XITS Math`. `Helvetica` and `Times` do not have such tables. Also, load either `mathspec` or `unicode-math`, but not both.

Comment: @karlkoeller: The above MWE is not working. Could you please advise how do run successfully. I will use `mathspec` or `unicode-math`. But my document required two different `math` setup. how do achieve this?

Comment: as @karlkoeller says `\setmathsfont{Times}` is wrong, you have to use a unicode math font (stix is designed to match a document using Times as body font)

Comment: @David: Actually i have using main font is `Times LT Std`. For the MWE only i have used `times`, because that font is not a free-font. Could you please advise how do use `2 different math fonts` in my documents.

Comment: It doesn't matter which Times you have, you can only use the math fonts listed in the unicode math documentation. (You can arrange for other fonts to be used for specific math alphabet commands `\something{abc}` but the main math symbol font has to be from a font designed for that use.

Comment: `XITS Math` or `TeX Gyre Termes` are amongst the maths fonts that are Times like.

Comment: There is no sans serif math font that can be used with `unicode-math`. So you're bound to `mathspec`, if you really want sans serif for tables (which I find bad). Surely you can't use `unicode-math` and `mathspec` together. The alternative is using traditional math fonts.