# How to select monospaced numerals for tables only when using mathspec?

Tags: tables, fonts, xetex, siunitx, mathspec

For one of my documents I used OldStyle numerals in regular text. For math I use Lining numbers. For tabular material I would like to use monospaced lining numbers if these numbers are math-related (I format those using the `S` column type from the `siunitx` package). 
However, up till now I haven't been able to get this last part to work. I'm using XeLaTeX with the `mathspec` package.

In the MWE below I first set the main font ([Alegreya Sans](https://github.com/huertatipografica/Alegreya-Sans)) and the default (non-Monospaced) math font (as an aside, probably not relevant to this question I'm using [Fira Sans](https://github.com/mozilla/Fira) for Greek letters, but the the other characters from Alegreya Sans).

In my partial solution as shown in the MWE I tell `siunitx` to treat the numbers as text and then switch the main font just before starting the `tabular` material. By putting this in curly braces and closing them before the caption, numbers in the caption look fine (OldStyle, non-Monospace). However, as you can see in the first column this also obviously changes the numbers in the first column, which I would like to keep OldStyle and non-Monospace.

Is there a way to simply switch math font somewhere in the text? The `mathspec` manual (and my experience) show that using `\setmathsfont{}` outside the preamble doesn't work. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231911/7221) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225537/7221) which uses `\setmathfont[version=something]`, but that requires the `unicode-math` package, which I don't need (and which seems to do more harm than good in my document, since I'm not planning to use Unicode symbols when typesetting math).

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[]{mathspec}

\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,BoldFont={Alegreya Sans Bold}]{Alegreya Sans}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Numbers={Lining},BoldFont={Fira Sans Medium},Scale=0.90]{Fira Sans Book}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin)[Numbers={Lining},BoldFont={Alegreya Sans Bold}]{Alegreya Sans}
\setmathsf[Numbers={Lining},BoldFont={Alegreya Sans Bold}]{Alegreya Sans}
% The following is needed to get units typeset correctly when using \SI{}{}
\setmathrm[Numbers={Lining},BoldFont={Alegreya Sans Bold}]{Alegreya Sans}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Table~\ref{tab:monospaced} should show monospaced, lining numbers. The
following numbers should not be monospaced and should be OldStyle:
0123456789. Testing siunitx: \SI{123}{mm}.
\begin{table}
  \centering
  {
    \sisetup{mode=text}
    \setmainfont[Numbers={Monospaced,Lining},BoldFont={Alegreya Sans Bold}]{Alegreya Sans}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.6] @{}}
      Text & {People} & {Miles} & {Boats} & {Time}\\
      \hline
      Something & 999 & 75 & 13 & 12.3456\\
      I want OldStyle here 12 & 111 & 54 & 11 & 0.111456\\
      I want OldStyle here 99 & 151 & 991 & 22 & 0.987611
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{This table should be correctly formatted. The math/siunitx
    numbers should be Monospaced and Lining. These numbers in the
    caption should be OldStyle: 0123456789.}
  \label{tab:monospaced}
\end{table}

To verify the fonts aren't changed permanently,
Table~\ref{tab:defaultFont} shows the same table, but with default
fonts settings.
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.6] @{}}
    Text & {People} & {Miles} & {Boats} & {Time}\\
    \hline
    Something & 999 & 75 & 13 & 12.3456\\
    I want OldStyle here 12 & 111 & 54 & 11 & 0.111456\\
    I want OldStyle here 99 & 151 & 991 & 22 & 0.987611
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with the default font settings for comparison.
    These numbers in the caption should be OldStyle and not
    Monospaced: 0123456789.}
  \label{tab:defaultFont}
\end{table}
The following numbers should not be monospaced and should be OldStyle:
0123456789.
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

**The following was added after the original question was asked.**

Based on @Henri Menke's suggestions in the comments I tried to wrap the tabular part in an `\addfontfeatures` block (as is done in section 7.3 of the `fontspec` manual). Looking at the output this results in Monospaced OldStyle numbers in column 1 (not exactly what I want, but acceptable). However, now the numbers in the other columns (formatted by `siunitx`) become Oldstyle (strange!) and are non-Monospaced. This may just be the undefined behaviour mentioned in the `fontspec` manual.

This is the code for Table 1:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{mode=text}
  \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.6] @{}}
      Text & {People} & {Miles} & {Boats} & {Time}\\
      \hline
      Something & 999 & 75 & 13 & 12.3456\\
      I want OldStyle here 12 & 111 & 54 & 11 & 0.111456\\
      I want OldStyle here 99 & 151 & 991 & 22 & 0.987611
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{This table should be correctly formatted. The math/siunitx
    numbers should be Monospaced and Lining. These numbers in the
    caption should be OldStyle: 0123456789.}
  \label{tab:monospaced}
\end{table}
```

[image: another test run]

In order to try and fix this I also removed the `\sisetup{mode=text}` line. As you can see below, this is almost getting where I want. The numerals in the first column are OldStyle , but Monospaced (not exactly what I want, but acceptable), however, the numerals in the other (math) columns are Lining (what I want), but non-Monospaced. So my conclusion is that the `\addfontfeatures` line only affects numbers in the main font, not in the math font.

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.6] @{}}
      Text & {People} & {Miles} & {Boats} & {Time}\\
      \hline
      Something & 999 & 75 & 13 & 12.3456\\
      I want OldStyle here 12 & 111 & 54 & 11 & 0.111456\\
      I want OldStyle here 99 & 151 & 991 & 22 & 0.987611
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{This table should be correctly formatted. The math/siunitx
    numbers should be Monospaced and Lining. These numbers in the
    caption should be OldStyle: 0123456789.}
  \label{tab:monospaced}
\end{table}
```

[image: another example]

Comment: You should use `\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}` instead of again calling `\setmainfont`.

Comment: I haven't tested, but with the `etoolbox` package, you might be able to use `\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, the reason why I didn't use `\addfontfeatures` is because the `fontspec` manual (section 7.3) says: "Note however that the behaviour in this regard will be unreliable (subject to the font itself) if you attempt to change an already selected feature", which I interpreted as "be careful when trying to set a feature that is mutually exclusive with another feature", so in order to avoid any possible mix up/undefined behaviour I chose to simple set the main font.

Comment: Nevertheless I tried to wrap the `tabular` part of the table in a `\addfontfeatures` block. See my updated question. As for your `\AtBeginEnvironment` suggestion: yes, I am planning to use that once I figured out the exact details of the font problem. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem is: if you use the default `mode=math` for `siunitx`, don't you get what you want?

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem is that I define my default math fonts (rm and sf) to have Lining numbers (non-Monospaced), i.e. for use in equations. However, in the tables I would like to have Lining and Monospaced numbers for `S` type columns. And because LaTeX apparently fixes the math fonts in the preamble, there doesn't seem to be a way to modify the math fonts only in the `tabular` environment.  The default (`mode=math`) is what is shown in Table 2.

Answer (score 3):

#### Problems

1. `siunitx` overrides any other font settings because it gets the final say.
2. The OP's way of specifying fonts for `tabular` are incompatible because it asks for the math font to be proportional lining yet monospaced lining at the same time...
3. ...and they can't be changed because (from the `fontspec` manual):

   > When \setmainfont, \setsansfont and \setmonofont are used in the preamble, they also define the fonts to be used in maths mode inside the \mathrm-type commands. This only occurs in the preamble because LaTeX freezes the maths fonts after this stage of the processing. The fontspec package must also be loaded after any maths font packages (e.g., euler) to be successful.

[image: Problems with the original]

#### Solution

Having tried a variety of ways, the only solution I can find is to drop the conflicting requirements for math mode (body) to be proportional lining but math mode (table) to be monospaced lining. The neatest seems to be dropping the requirement to be proportional.

The code can be simplified:

#### Minimal MWE:

```latex
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
\setmathsfont(Greek)[Numbers={Lining},BoldFont={Fira Sans Medium},Scale=0.90]{Fira Sans Book}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin)[Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
\setmathsf[Numbers={Lining,Proportional},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
% The following is needed to get units typeset correctly when using \SI{}{}
\setmathrm[Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx}
```

#### Full MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
%\setmathsfont(Greek)[Numbers={Lining},BoldFont={Fira Sans Medium},Scale=0.90]{Fira Sans Book}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin)[Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
\setmathsf[Numbers={Lining,Proportional},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
% The following is needed to get units typeset correctly when using \SI{}{}
\setmathrm[Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},BoldFont={AlegreyaSans-Bold.otf}]{AlegreyaSans-Regular.otf}
\usepackage[mode=math]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

For one of my documents I used proportional OldStyle numerals in regular text:\\
x = 1234567890 111 888\\
x = 0123456789 888 111\\
But math should be proportional lining but as that's impossible we'll settle for monospaced lining:\\
\ensuremath{x = 1234567890 111 888}\\
\ensuremath{x = 0123456789 888 111}

For math I use Lining numbers. For tabular material I would like to use monospaced lining numbers if these numbers are math-related.

Table~\ref{tab:monospaced} should show monospaced, lining numbers. The
following numbers should be proportional and OldStyle:
1234567890. Testing siunitx: \SI{1234567890}{mm}.
\begin{table}[!hb]
  \centering
  {
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.6] @{}}
      Text & {People} & {Miles} & {Boats} & {Time}\\
      \hline
      Something & 999 & 75 & 13 & 12.3456\\
      I want OldStyle proportional here 12 & 111 & 54 & 11 & 0.111456\\
      I want OldStyle proportional here 99 & 151 & 991 & 22 & 0.987611
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{This table should be correctly formatted. The math/siunitx
    numbers should be Monospaced and Lining. These numbers in the
    caption should be OldStyle and proportional: 0123456789.}
  \label{tab:monospaced}
\end{table}

To verify the fonts aren't changed permanently,
Table~\ref{tab:defaultFont} shows the same table, but with default
fonts settings. Given that OP's requirements and the changes I have made, the OP's typesetting for Table~\ref{tab:defaultFont} should be the same as Table~\ref{tab:monospaced} and the comment `To verify the fonts aren't changed permanently' is obsolete.
\begin{table}[!hb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=3]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2]S[table-format=2.6] @{}}
    Text & {People} & {Miles} & {Boats} & {Time}\\
    \hline
    Something & 999 & 75 & 13 & 12.3456\\
    I want OldStyle proportional here 12 & 111 & 54 & 11 & 0.111456\\
    I want OldStyle proportional here 99 & 151 & 991 & 22 & 0.987611
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with the default font settings for comparison.
    These numbers in the caption should be OldStyle and Proportional: 0123456789.}
  \label{tab:defaultFont}
\end{table}

For one of my documents I used proportional OldStyle numerals in regular text:\\
x = 1234567890 111 888\\
x = 0123456789 888 111\\
But math should be proportional lining but has to be monospaced lining:\\
\ensuremath{x = 1234567890 111 888}\\
\ensuremath{x = 0123456789 888 111}
\end{document}
```

#### Full MWE Output

[image: Output allowing monospaced math everywhere]

#### Update

Given that math font and its features are fixed in the preamble, I guess you could use combinations of `\text` with `\addfontfeatures` to adjust the appearance of numbers in running text to emulate the math style.

#### Version

This is currently working on

- `XeTeX` Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)
- `mathspec` 2016/12/22 v0.2b
- `siunitx` 2020/05/25